# existing documents in a library not appear when saving new one

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

When I click save button to save back the newly create document (by clicking on New Document button) none of existing documents within the library appears in the dialog. why? is it a normal in SharePoint? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new document based on the template you have selected for the Document Library. For example a new "Word" document. So your dialog is in Excel or in Word and has a preselected file extension in the save dialog.

I guess "*.docx" is preselected when you create a new Word file so you only see files in the target library that also have that extension.

Of course you can select another file name extension or enter manuall "*.*" in the file name section of the dialog to see different files or all files (inside the document library).

Comment: Yes "*.docx" is preselected, I have alrady created about 10 another documents with same template and they exists in the library but when I save a new document with same extension based on same template I can't see any document in the dialog.

Comment: And you are sure that the file extensions do match. Are the files in the library all "docx" files? Maybe you have some event receiver that alters the file after upload?

Comment: I am sure that all files have same extension and I have only one conent type in the library. there is no event receiver.

Comment: so what happens when you enter "*.*" into the filename textbox inside the dialog?

Comment: Nothing happend.